# How to parcel a short[] array?

Tags: android, parcelable

How can I parcel the following parameter?

```
short[] types;
```

Since now I've tried this:

```
// Write to parcel
dest.writeValue(types);

// Read from parcel
???
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Short [] sd = new Short[count];   
dest.writeArray(sd);

Comment: Not aplicable for short[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short array can't write and read directly from parcel.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html

You may try like this.

```
// write
dest.writeInt(types.length);
for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    dest.writeInt((int) types[i]);
}

// read
len = parcel.readInt();
short[] types = new short[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    types[i] = (short) parcel.readInt();
}
```

Comment: I can't convert the array to a list easily. So I tried a type conventions... I think maybe a better solutions exists.